# PHP parsing external site

Tags: php

I do not have any experience in parsing external url's to grab some data from, but today i've try some experiments:

```
$str1 = file_get_contents('http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge');
$test1 = strstr($str1, "amount medium clearfix");
$parts = explode(">",$test1);
$parts2 = vsprintf("%s", $parts[1]);

$str2 = file_get_contents('http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge');
$test2 = strstr($str2, "money-raised goal");
$test3 = str_ireplace("money-raised goal", "", "$test2");
$test4 = str_ireplace("\"", "", "$test3");
$test5 = str_ireplace(">", "", "$test4");
$test6 = substr($test5, 0, 29);
$test7 = explode("Raised of", $test6);
$test8 = vsprintf("%s", $test7[1]);
```

try the code with:

`print_r($parts2);`  then with `print_r($test8);` and then with `echo "$parts2 - $test8";`

Because it's so popular this days the Ubuntu Edge campaign i have try to get the two fields from site (only as a experiment), but without success. 
Well it grabs the two fields, but i could not put both in the same variable. The output is or the $parts2, or the $parts2 contain the value of test8, or only the $test8.

What i'm doing wrong, and why? Also is there a simpler method to do what i want, without so much code?

Comment: Could use a [domparser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: try that already, included the simple...php then file_get_html, then some sort of non functional examples (try with the solution from stackoverflow), but without success, and decides to go native, without external lib...

Comment: That is not going native. Using DOMDocument is native and a good idea.

Comment: EJTH: could you please provide a simple functional example of using a DOM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Well it grabs the two fields, but i could not put both in the same
>   variable.

Not sure what you mean there.

> Also is there a simpler method to do what i want, without so much
>   code?

Without so much code? No. More flexible and (possibly) efficient? Yes.

Try this and tailor it to your liking

```
<?php
$page = file_get_contents('http://www.indiegogo.com/projects/ubuntu-edge');

$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($page);

$finder = new DomXPath($doc);

// find class="money-raised"
$nodes = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'money-raised')]");

// get the children of the first match  (class="money-raised")
$raised_children = $nodes->item(0)->childNodes;

// get the children of the second match (class="money-raised goal")
$goal_children = $nodes->item(1)->childNodes;

// get the amount value
$money_earned = $raised_children->item(1)->nodeValue;

// get the amount value
preg_match('/\$[\d,]+/', $goal_children->item(0)->nodeValue, $m);
$money_earned_goal = $m[0];


echo "Money earned: $money_earned\n";
echo "Goal: $money_earned_goal\n";

?>
```

This has eleven lines of code without the `echos` (compared to your 12 lines), but only calls the other site **once**. Scraping websites is a somewhat involved task. This code gets exactly the values you wanted from this exact page.

If you want to scrape sites, I strongly recommend learning to use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and [DOMXPath](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php). There is a lot to learn, but it's worth the effort.

Comment: much more complicated than my example, but 100% functional...Thank you for your answer. BTW, how do you investigate that you have the exact value what you need, because if i go step by step with print_r or var_dump on every line, it gives me nothing useful.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Basically, I construct the DOM code while looking at the HTML. We need to find all the elements where class="money-earned". This gives me a DOMNodeList containing 2 elements corresponding to the 2 `<p>` tags with that class. I see that the first element has one of the values I want inside a `<span>` tag, which is a child of the first "node" in the list. It helps to use `nodeName` instead of `nodeValue` as that gives the name of the tag. So, basically, trial and error. :P

Comment: You'll become more proficient as you learn to use DOMDocument. It is more complicated than your example, but so is the structure of HTML. Scraping can also be more complicated than searching for strings, especially when you want to locate and copy entire sections. DOMDocument serves that purpose very well, so it's worth learning and practicing.

Comment: BTW: var_dump gives you the type of object, DOMNodeList, DOMElement, etc. From there you can use the PHP docs to find out what you need.

Comment: Thank's. You understand my question after all. Tomorrow i will try to use DOM to make some scraping to a random page. :)

Comment: Actually the simplehtmldom parser mentioned by @DarkBee is not bad either. And it is not an "external lib" as you say, as its written  completely in PHP. Its alot simpler to use than DOMDocument (But probably slower, since PHP is "slow" compared to extensions written in C), but either one will do the job in most cases.